# How to prepend column names into column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Having the following table:

```
| Some Table      |
| Id | Name | Age |
| 23 | Marc | 41  |
| 54 | Edu  | 34  |
```

I want to get:

```
|Another Table's Column| Id    | Name      | Age     |
| .....                | Id@23 | Name@Marc | Age@41  |
| .....                | Id@54 | Name@Edu  | Age@34  |
```

This query will be used inside a dynamic sql, the name of the table is going to have passed as a parameter.

The final query must show data of at least two tables, and only one of them must show data with his column names as a prefix.

Comment: You can investigate `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to get column names

Comment: The question is bit unclear. What do you mean by "only one of them must show data with his column names as a prefix"? If we can have two tables data and some output it may be more clear

Comment: Presumably you want something like `DECLARE @ VARCHAR(MAX) = ''; SELECT @+= ', ''' + COLUMN_NAME + '@'' + CAST(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'` and a dynamic query around that?

Comment: So here are some more questions. Do you know how many fields and what fields will be selected from the table being passed in as a parameter? and on which column it should be joined by the other table?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want, but here is the script to show column names within the result for any passed table:

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(128) = '[Person].[Person]';
DECLARE @l NVARCHAR(2000) = '';
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(4000) = '';

SELECT @l = (
SELECT ' ''@' + Name + ''' + CAST([' + Name + '] as VARCHAR(max)) as [' + Name + '],'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@t)
ORDER BY column_id
FOR XML PATH(''));

SELECT @s = 'SELECT ' + LEFT(@l,LEN(@l)-1) + ' FROM ' + @t + ';'

PRINT @s
EXEC (@s)
```

You can tune it to link another table or many tables